# Linux + how to clean /boot and stay only with the current kernel version files

Tags: linux, redhat, kernel, rpm, grub

Under **/boot** we have the following files ( red-hat Linux version 6.6 )

```
 cd /boot
 # ls -ltr

  drwx------ 2 root root    12288 Oct 15  2015 lost+found
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4152624 Oct 15  2015 vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
 -rw------- 1 root root  6084011 Oct 15  2015 initrd-2.6.32- 504.30.3.el6.x86_64kdump.img
  drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     1024 Oct 15  2015 efi
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106371 Oct 15  2015 config-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2546171 Oct 15  2015 System.map-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   200246 Oct 15  2015 symvers-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.gz
 -rw------- 1 root root 19360700 Oct 15  2015 initramfs-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.img
 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4222736 Nov 23  2015 vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   107139 Nov 23  2015 config-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2585672 Nov 23  2015 System.map-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   206008 Nov 23  2015 symvers-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64.gz
 -rw------- 1 root root 24340354 Jul 16 03:20 initramfs-2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64.img
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     1024 Jul 16 03:20 grub
```

Because **/boot** size is very small, (**90M size**)

We want to delete the previous kernel from **/boot** include **ALL** the other files that related to this kernel

**The current running kernel version**

```
 # uname -r
 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64
```

So now I want to capture all the files that are not related to the *current* kernel , and can be deleted from the **/boot**

*egrep -v will do the Job*

```
  # ls -ltr | egrep -v "2.6.32-573.12.1|lost\+found|grub|efi"

  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4152624 Oct 15  2015 vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
  -rw------- 1 root root  6084011 Oct 15  2015 initrd-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64kdump.img
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   106371 Oct 15  2015 config-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2546171 Oct 15  2015 System.map-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   200246 Oct 15  2015 symvers-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.gz
  -rw------- 1 root root 19360700 Oct 15  2015 initramfs-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.img

  # rpm -qa | grep "2.6.32-504.30.3"
  kernel-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
```

**so my plan is to perform the following**

1. Remove the previos kernel

   ```
   rpm –e  kernel-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
   ```
2. Remove the following files from **/boot**

   ```
   rm config-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64 
   rm System.map-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64
   rm symvers-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.gz
   rm initramfs-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.x86_64.img
   ```

**My question:**

Is my plan is **risky ?** , or I can be **sure** that my procedure is safe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer should work but thought i'd mention 'Yum-utils' can make this simpler

1. Check what kernels are installed with: `rpm -q kernel`
2. install yum utils: `yum install yum-utils`
3. Package cleanup where count is how many kernels you want to retain: `package-cleanup --oldkernels --count=2`

Answer (score 0):

I think your plan is overly complicated.

The files you're suggesting to remove in step 2 are likely all owned by the relevant kernel package anyway. On my test RHEL 6 machine:

`$ rpm -qf /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64.img 
kernel-2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64`

etc.

So step 1 should remove everything. As for what to remove, `rpm -qa kernel\*` will list all of the kernel packages installed. Simply grep out what doesn't match `uname -r`. Take care how this might affect your GRUB configuration but if you stay within the RHEL frameworks then GRUB should only reference kernels that are installed.